# Amazon Cloudformation stack hangs after Lambda function completes

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have a simple template to create an S3 bucket and then call my Lambda function to copy an object to it from a public bucket:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Create an S3 Bucket, populate it with a copy of a sample CSV file
Parameters:
  bucketname:
    Type: String
    Description: Name of bucket where the CSV file will be bootstrapped, bucket names MUST be unique across AWS and no Upper Case characters - 8 or more characters
    MinLength: 8
Outputs:
  bucketURL:
    Value:
      Fn::Join:
        - ''
        - - 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/'
          - !Ref bucketname
Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref bucketname
  deploytos3:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      CodeUri: 's3://mongodb-aws-jam/lambdaDeploy.zip'
      Policies:
        - AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
        - AmazonS3FullAccess
  DeploymentCustomResource:
    Type: Custom::deploytos3
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt deploytos3.Arn
      bucketname: !Ref bucketname
```

This is the Lambda function:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var response = require('cfn-response');

const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const srcBucket = "mongodb-aws-jam"
const srcKey = "SampleData.csv"

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    console.log("start")
    myBucket = event.ResourceProperties['bucketname']
    console.log(`Will bootstrap ${srcKey} object in ${myBucket} bucket`)

    const copyparams = {
        Bucket : myBucket,
        CopySource : `/${srcBucket}/${srcKey}`,
        Key : srcKey
    };

    try {
        await s3.copyObject(copyparams).promise();
    } catch (error) {
        const errorText = `Failed to copy file to ${myBucket}/${srcKey}: error`
        console.log(errorText)
        // callback(null, {statusCode: 500, body: errorText})
        response.send(event, context, response.FAILED, {Error: errorText})
        return
    }
    resultText = `Copied file to ${myBucket}/${srcKey}`
    console.log(resultText)
    // callback(null, {statusCode: 200, body: resultText})
    response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, {})
};
```

The stack succeeds in creating and bootstrapping the new bucket, but the stack history shows that the `DeploymentCustomResource` resource never gets past the `CREATE_IN_PROGRESS` status, even though the lambda logs show that the function completed successfully. I've tried various alternatives to using the callback, and reduced the function to doing no work, but the stack always hangs.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue was because `handler` was asynchronous.

This is the working function:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const response = require('cfn-response');

const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const srcBucket = "mongodb-aws-jam"
const srcKey = "SampleData.csv"

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  var bucket = event.ResourceProperties.bucketname;
  console.log(`Bucket: ${bucket}`);
  const copyparams = {
    Bucket : bucket,
    CopySource : `/${srcBucket}/${srcKey}`,
    Key : srcKey
  };
  s3.copyObject(copyparams).promise()
  .then (() => {
      var responseData = {Value: bucket};
      console.log("Success");
      response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, responseData);
  }, error => {
      const errorText = `Failed to copy file to ${bucket}/${srcKey}: ${error}`
      console.log(errorText)
      response.send(event, context, response.FAILED, {Error: errorText})
  })
};
```

Comment: you are right! Thanks for raising this issue, now chaps can find it.

Answer (score 0):

Your function gets stuck in `CREATE_IN_PROGRESS` since CloudFormation (CFN) **waits for correct response** from the function. Your code does not provide it.

Functions for custom resources require **special design**. The have to handle CFN event correctly, and respond accordingly.

For functions in nodejs, you can use **helper library** `cfn-response` as shown in [cfn-response module](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-lambda-function-code-cfnresponsemodule.html). Examples of cusstom resource functions in nodejs are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-lambda-function-code-cfnresponsemodule.html#w2ab1c27c24c14b9c13).

Comment: I've also tried with `cfn-response`, e.g. `var response = require('cfn-response'); ... response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, {})`
but the custom resource remains in the `CREATE_IN_PROGRESS` state.

Comment: @AndrewMorgan Adding `var response = require('cfn-response')` is not enough. You have to fully re-write your function to conform to CFN custom resource format. I suggest checking documentation and examples how such functions should be designed.

Comment: I am following the example by calling `response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, {})`. I see `Response body: {"Status":"SUCCESS","Reason":"See the details in CloudWatch Log Stream: 2020/10/12/[$LATEST]...` in the logs. What else is missing?

Comment: @AndrewMorgan Can you update your question with new version of the code?

Comment: @AndrewMorgan I guess that you've bundled the `cfn-response` module with your function?